# Photo Competition: October - OOPS

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per contest.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself/person with you.
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content
5. Only upvotes count towards winning.

---

Rules for October are as follows:

1. **OOPS - Somebody being clumsy in TGO. Should be funny, or, if not hilarious, at least mildly amusing.**
2. The contest will last the whole month of October and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
3. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

---

Suggest a theme for the next contest.

1. Leave a **single** comment below in the format
     THEME - ONE SENTENCE DESCRIPTION
2. Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Rick stuck]
But it has 4 wheel drive, why am I stuck?

Taken about 2007, ORV trails in Washington State. Drivers first time wheeling, and a bit unfamiliar with the capabilities of a stock 4x4 Jeep.

Comment: This photo had the most votes at the end of the month. So I say James Jenkins has won.

Answer (score 8):

## Stepping stones gone wrong

[image: falling in the river]

Taken Saturday 11th November 2006, [near Dartmeet](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=50.5422560&mlon=-3.8767383&zoom=14).

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the East Aligator river causeway into Arnheim land.  As you can see from the vehicle to our left, this is a tidal river.

Photo taken by me from a tour bus in June 2017.

[image: 4x4 quick getaway]